# What sort of sensors can and can't be connected to the Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, sensor

I'm new to the Raspberry Pi so apologies if this question is basic. I would like to know if a sensor or bit of hardware has to be *made* to work with the Raspberry Pi or whether any sensor can be adapted to work with it.

I ask this as i would like to use the Raspberry Pi in conjunction with a wood moisture sensor but I have no idea whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Please add a link to the sensor to your question. What interface if any does this use, I am assuming this is an analog sensor, so at the least will need an ADC to work with the Pi.

Comment: I'm thinking of using a protimeter of some sort. Something similar to this http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/171834250454?adgroupid=13585920426&hlpht=true&hlpv=2&rlsatarget=kwd-123671539986&adtype=pla&ff3=1&lpid=122&poi=&ul_noapp=true&limghlpsr=true&device=c&chn=ps&campaignid=207297426&crdt=0&ff12=67&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff14=122&viphx=1&ops=true&ff13=80

Comment: That is more a system than a sensor.  I would check with the seller.  I suspect it needs special hardware/software at the barrel end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. For the time being, I'm going to use a wood moisture meter to monitor the dry rot manually. But I would like to find something similar that can be connected to the raspberry pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be made for Raspberry Pi, it just has to be able to connect via USB or a GPIO pin using a supported protocol, such as I2C, SPI, UART, and standard RasPi GPIO. If you see this article [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi07.pdf), you can theoretically use anything supported by Arduino as well.

However, if you tell me which sensor this is, I can give you exact information on comparability.